# Rewrite existing subdirectory to top level domain using .htaccess rewrites

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nuxt.js

hope you're all OK!

I'm having what feels like a simple issue which I just can't seem to resolve.

So for context. I have static PWA audio player (Nuxt) living in a subdirectory on my test domain e.g:

http://mytestdomain.com/player/

The top level domain "http://mytestdomain.com" is a Laravel 8.0 install to which the PWA makes api calls.

Essentially I need any url prefixed with "player/laravel" to redirect to the top level domain so:

http://mytestdomain.com/player/laravel/api/auth/login

To rewrite to
http://mytestdomain.com/api/auth/login

This is my .htaccess for my Laravel installation in /web/public/

The "player" folder is also in /web/public/player

The DocumentRoot has already been set to /web/public/ via ISP config.

As I understand it the rule should work: RewriteRule ^player/laravel/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]

However all I get is a 404? I'm clearly missing something here?

Do I need to place a .htaccess in the /player/ directory?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^player/laravel/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greately appreciated!

Comment: Could you please changing your rule from `^player/laravel/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]` TO `^player/laravel/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]` without a `/`?

Comment: This might be a limitation of your Laravel app, not `.htaccess`. How are you routing URLs in Laravel? Are you using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for instance? In that case Laravel is still "seeing" the requested URL, ie. `/player/laravel/api/auth/login`, not the rewritten URL `/api/auth/login` - which is presumably required to route the request in Laravel?